# How do I remove black rectangles on the desktop screen in os x 10.8?

Tags: macos, bug

Shown to the left of the screen, on the middle.

Moving a window over it does not remove it, however restarting does. But then they reappear after a while.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question to mention what Mac or graphics cards you have or add any relevant log messages? Have you tried quitting background applications or other processes?

Comment: Interesting but not enough information to track it down. Please run the Apple hardware test http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509